# StructureMap not recognising TheCallingAssembly

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

am kinnda new to IOC and StructureMap. WHen i am trying to call the TheCallingAssembly() method, its not recognising it.

Someone please help

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => 
            {
                x.Scan(y =>
                {
                   // y.TheCallingAssembly();
                    y.LookForRegistries();
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In version 3, this has been moved to the StructureMap.Graph namespace.

Simply add **using StructureMap.Graph** to your project.